# Encountering an "undefined alias or unknown mapping" exception when using NHibernate's Multi Query feature

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to implement a NHibernate's Multi Query feature for a typical Paging and Counting functionality using NHibernate version v2.0.50727.

I've been following the example given [here](http://ayende.com/blog/1895/nhibernate-mutli-query-support) by Ayende Rahien and my code is a lot similar to it. However, every time it hits the call to return the results as a list, an exception is thrown with the message along the lines of:

```
"undefined alias or unknown mapping: Shop [from Shop.dbo.Sales s where s.Customer = :customer_id and s.date between :start_date and :end_date order by s.date desc]"
```

Here is the step in the code where the problem occurs:

```
        IList queryResults = NHibernateSession.CreateMultiQuery()
            .Add(dataQuery)
            .Add(countQuery)
            .List();
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
        private IList < SalesDetails > GetSalesByCustomer(Customer customer, DateTime start, DateTime end, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int TotalCount)
     {
        IQuery dataQuery = NHibernateSession.CreateQuery("from Shop.dbo.Sales s where s.Customer = :customer_id and s.date between :start_date and :end_date order by s.date desc");
        dataQuery.SetInt32("customer_id", customer.ID);
        dataQuery.SetParameter("start_date", start);
        dataQuery.SetParameter("end_date", end);
        dataQuery.SetFirstResult(pageIndex);
        dataQuery.SetMaxResults(pageSize);

        IQuery countQuery = NHibernateSession.CreateQuery("select count(*) from Shop.dbo.Sales s where s.Customer = :customer_id and s.date between :start_date and :end_date");
        countQuery.SetInt32("customer_id", customer.ID);
        countQuery.SetParameter("start_date", start);
        countQuery.SetParameter("end_date", end);

        IList queryResults = NHibernateSession.CreateMultiQuery()
            .Add(dataQuery)
            .Add(countQuery)
            .List();

        IList < SalesDetails > results = (IList < SalesDetails > ) queryResults[0];
        TotalCount = (int)((IList) queryResults[1])[0];
        return results;
    }
```

Do you need to provide a mapping for this to work? I didn’t think that was the case because it is being returned to a generic list, but if this was so, how would you even go about doing this in Hibernate's Mapping File, ie, hbm.xml, file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, and Ayende in the link you gave, are creating queries in [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) using the `CreateQuery` method. This type of NH query must be written against NH entities, which means you must have a proper mapping, i.e. a `Sales` entity, and then write `select count(*) from Sale` as Ayende selects from `Item`.

If you want to use SQL instead of using `CreateQuery`, you should use the `CreateSQLQuery` method. You could review chapters 14-17 of [the manual](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html). Too bad you are using the old version, or I'd advise you to make linq your query method of choice.

In short - replace

```
NHibernateSession.CreateQuery("select ..
```

with

```
NHibernateSession.CreateSQLQuery("select ..
```

or write a proper HQL query using your mapped entity name instead of the SQL table based identifiers.